# Powershell: Referencing a single element in an Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, reference

I would like to reference a single element inside an array, using the [ref] keyword.

How to test for a reference:

```
$var1 = "this is a string"
[ref]$var2 = [ref]$var1

$var2.Value
this is a string

$var2.Value += " too!"
$var2.Value
this is a string too!

$var1
this is a string too!
```

The above is working as expected. But now to reference a single element inside any array?

```
$var3="string 1", "string 2", "string 3"
[ref]$var2=[ref]($var3[1])

$var2.Value
string 2

$var2.Value += " updated!"
$var2.Value
string 2 updated!

$var3[1]
string 2
```

I expected `$var3[1]` to return the same as the value of `$var2.Value`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell, **you *cannot* obtain a reference to *individual elements of an array*.**

To gain *write* access to a specific element of an array, your only option is:

- to use a reference to the array *as a whole*
- *and* to reference the element of interest *by index*.

In other words:

Given `$var3 = "string 1", "string 2", "string 3"`, **the *only* way to *modify* the 2nd element of the array stored in `$var3` is to use `$var3[1] = ...`** (barring acrobatics via C# code compiled on demand).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `[ref] $var2 = [ref] ($var3[1])`

In PowerShell, **if you *get* the value of `$var3[1]`, it is invariably a *copy* of the data stored in `$var3`'s 2nd element** (which may be a copy of the *actual data*, if the element contains an instance of a *value type*, or a copy of the *reference* to the instance of a *reference type*, otherwise).

Casting that *copy* to [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) is therefore invariably disassociated from the array element of origin.